# Iterating through all of a user's feed using the Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to iterate through all posts a user has ever made to their feed:

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire

                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                var fbid = response.authResponse.userID;

                console.time('all posts');

                var url = '/me/feed?limit=100';
                var finished = false;
                var c = 0, totalLikes = 0;
                var timer = setInterval(function () {

                    if(url != '') {
                        console.log("Checking: " + url);
                        FB.api(url, function(response) {

                            //console.log("Got " + response.data.length + " items");

                            //c += response.data.length;

                            // calculate total likes
                            for(var k in response.data) {
                                c++;
                                if(response.data[k].from.id == fbid) {
                                    console.log(response.data[k]);

                                }

                            }

                            if(response.paging) {
                                var bits = response.paging.next.split('facebook.com');
                                url = bits[1];
                            } else { 
                                clearInterval(timer); 
                                console.log("Found a total of " + c + " items");
                                console.timeEnd('all posts')
                            }
                        });
                        url = '';
                    } else {
                         //console.log("Skipped iteration");
                    }
                }, 1000);

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app

                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                    }
                }, { scope: 'user_about_me,read_stream,user_status,user_photos,friends_about_me,user_checkins,friends_likes,user_actions.music' });

            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                console.log("not logged in");
            }   
        });
```

Unfortunately it appears that as it is iterating through the pages, no updates are found paste 2011, then on the last page it finds two comments I made on another users's status in 2007. It's missing literally 100s of status updates I have made.

I've spent the last three hours researching this, to no avail. I have tried with 3 different people's accounts (all of whom have lots of status updates etc. before 2011) and they have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

The URL you have specified   `var url = '/me/feed?limit=100';` so it is only returning the first 100.  You can try to increase the limit and also use the offset like this:

`var url = '/me/feed?limit=100&offset=101`

The relevant api docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Upon further searching it seems there are some logged bugs with regards to history.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178108638946497?browse=search_4fabbf595050e1514377846

Comment: The documentation indicates that limit merely limits the number of results on each page. My understanding was that the paging.next property in the JSON object will correctly take me to the next URL.

I can't find any reference that uses the syntax you describe (it merely suggests them as parameters)

I tried something like this using the Graph API explorer: `/me/feed?limit=2&offset=10` and `/me/feed?limit=2&offset=10` but it stopped returning data around offset 10. I am not sure this is the correct solution...

Comment: Let me edit my last comment.  Start with limit=100 and the next page should be `limit=100&offset=101` and `limit=100&offset=202` etc.  On their api page and manually testing that's the case and you should be able to successfully walk the pages. The next page does return these ruls but you can manually test them as well.  `{
previous: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=5&access_token=mytoken&since=1336449559&__previous=1",
next: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=5&access_token=mytoken&until=1336053590"
}`